# React context is undefined

Tags: reactjs

This is my first time using Reactjs with Laravel. I'm trying to send data among components but the context returns as undefined. I want to send data from Product_Detail.js to Cart.js

globalContext.js

```
import React from "react";

export const MContext = React.createContext(); //exporting context object

export class MyProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      message: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MContext.Provider value={{ message: "kkk" }}>
        <Cart />
        <Product_Detail />
        {this.props.children} //this indicates that all the child tags with
        MyProvider as Parent can access the global store.
      </MContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const MyConsumer = MContext.Consumer;
```

Cart.js

```
import { MyConsumer } from "./globalContext";

<MyConsumer>{context => <p>{console.log("CCC", context)}</p>}</MyConsumer>;

export default Cart;

if (document.getElementById("shoppingCart")) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Cart />, document.getElementById("shoppingCart"));
}
```

Product_Detail.js

```
import { MyConsumer } from "./globalContext";

<MyConsumer>
  {context => (
    <button
      className="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4"
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("kkkk", context);
      }}
    >
      Add to Cart
    </button>
  )}
</MyConsumer>;
export default Product_Detail;

if (document.getElementById("product_detail")) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Product_Detail />,
    document.getElementById("product_detail")
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import Cart from "./components/Website/Cart";
import Product_Detail from "./components/Website/Product_Detail";
import { MyProvider } from "./components/Website/globalContext";
```

Comment: suggestion : use **react-redux**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're rendering inside your app component, but I think what is going wrong is that your components are not correctly wrapped by your `Provider`.

Your `App` component should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Cart from "./components/Website/Cart";
import Product_Detail from "./components/Website/Product_Detail";
import { MyProvider } from "./components/Website/globalContext";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <Cart />
      <Product_Detail />
    </MyProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And your `globalContext` like this:

```
import React from "react";

export const MContext = React.createContext(); //exporting context object

export class MyProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MContext.Provider value={{ message: "kkk" }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const MyConsumer = MContext.Consumer;
```

This way the `value` you passed to your provider get's logged out when `Cart` is rendered and when you click on the button rendered by `Product_Detail`.

Also I'm assuming that you're importing React inside the `Cart` and `Product_Detail` components and that you're correctly defining these components.

Comment: It only works with my when i use class base but when puting the provider in function it returns undefined!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean exactly by putting the provider in a function as opposed to a class base? You could also create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?file=/src/App.js:0-27) that shows the problem you're describing and link it in a comment.

Comment: when I click *add to cart* button the value is undefined, thia is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-minsky-1fomr?file=/src/index.html

Comment: Also there's something I didn't comment on before, but why do you have two entry points `product_detail` and `shoppingCart`. Why don't you just have the usual single `root` element as your entry point?

Comment: the shopping cart is inside <Header /> -I didn't mention it here to simplify the question-  which I want to show it in this product_detail page and another pages..which I can't do If i put them inside one entry point

Comment: In most cases you don't need dom nodes other than one root node. If you do need more you could look into [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). Here's my fork of your sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wozniak-q6fd9?file=/src/App.js. The main problem was that you added parentheses when exporting the App component.